# SQL Database to big

Tags: sql, database, cut

I have one question regarding SQL 2005 Database `.mdf`.
I have one database and its more than 290 GB. I need cut this Database and I don’t know how.
For example, cut this by Date, take offline in a separate part as 2011-12-31 or older

Comment: what do you mean with cut by Date?

Comment: In SSMS object explorer, right click the database and choose Tasks -> Shrink -> Database. Now repeat for Files, does that do anything?

Comment: If you right click the database and go to properties -> Options, what is the recovery model?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the 290G is not mostly a huge transaction file that needs to be backed up or truncated?

How you choose to prune this database is entirely up to you. You could do it be a date column in your tables, if that is appropriate.  It really depends on the type of data being stored in your tables.